# Spot segmentation on grayscale images

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, grayscale

I am new to image processing and have the following question: how to detect black spots and areas on the images below?

[image]

[image]

The problem I am facing is that the black areas do not have sharp well-defined edges and image segmentation algorithms I have looked up so far assume smooth edges.

EDIT: Below is the image I would like to see which is also a response to Ian Chu who suggested a thresholding method, I use the user's answer to clarify my question  [image]

The brown areas are obtained by Ian Chu using thresholding. I would like also to mark small black spots around those areas. I marked them by orange ( sorry for the sloppy drawings). I hope that my question is now a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Otsu's to automatically choose the threshold, but you lose the ability to specifically choose what you want to mask.

[image]

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# mark holes
def mark(img):
    # crop margins
    margin = 5;
    img = img[margin:-margin,margin:-margin];
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    # threshold
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0);
    _, mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU);
    mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask);

    # redraw
    img[mask == 255] = (0,0,100);
    return img;

# load image
image1 = cv2.imread("spots1.png");
image2 = cv2.imread("spots2.png");

# mark image
image1 = mark(image1);
image2 = mark(image2);

# show
cv2.imshow("one", image1);
cv2.imshow("two", image2);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Is there a way to adjust a threshold automatically? Or do I need to hand tune it every time?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I may try K-means clustering as well